# Why can't I fetch a file in angular 2?

Tags: javascript, http, d3.js, angular

Basically I am trying to fetch a csv file to parse it later using d3. 
I have created a special component to fetch the data, and pass it to another component to parse it.

The fetch-data component is as follows:

```
import {Component, Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions, HttpModule} from "@angular/http";
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-fetch-data',
  templateUrl: './fetch-data.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./fetch-data.component.css'],
  providers: [HttpModule]
})

@Injectable()
export class FetchDataComponent {

  constructor(private http: Http) {
  }

  getCsv(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get('app/districts_data/data.csv').map((res: Response) => res);

  }

}
```

Here is the other component where the d3 code should go:

```
    import {Component, OnInit, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';
    import * as D3 from 'd3';
    import {FetchDataComponent} from '../fetch-data/fetch-data.component';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-dubai-dual-line-chart',
      templateUrl: './dubai-dual-line-chart.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./dubai-dual-line-chart.component.css'],
      providers: [FetchDataComponent]

    })
    export class parseData implements OnInit {

public csv;

  constructor(private __fetchDataComponent: FetchDataComponent) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getCsv();
  }

  private getCsv() {
    this.__fetchDataComponent.getCsv().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.csv = data
      },
      err => console.error(err),
      () => console.log('done loading csv')
    )
  }
}
```

But nothing seems to be fetched. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Are you using system.js or web pack at all?

Comment: I've attempted to replicate your problem [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZhGbYMDsu5TVb6c54pHM?p=preview).  It seems to work well...

Comment: Do you get an error message in the browser console?